# How to convert recordset to json array in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

i'm having one table like

```
  name | age 
   abc | 20
   pqr | 30
```

I want result in json array like

```
{
 [{
   "name":"abc",
   "age":20 
 },
 {
  "name":"pqr",
   "age":30 
 }]
}
```

I know their is method

```
row_to_json();
```

that will be give me only single row of json but i want array,
please help me on this

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
select json_agg(row_to_json(t))
from t
;
                      json_agg                      
----------------------------------------------------
 [{"name":"abc","age":20}, {"name":"pqr","age":30}]
```

Comment: A detail, even if it's obvious (it wasn't for me at the first sight): `t` is the `table name`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
SELECT array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(data)))
FROM (select name, age from your_table) data
```

You also can see more at this link:

https://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/faster-json-generation-with-postgresql

Hope it useful to you.